# Conditional Join that looks for a specific value as a preference, but otherwise accepts other values

Tags: join, conditional-statements

Let's say I have some customers with multiple phone numbers and some with only one number.  Anytime there is more than one number, there will *always* be a type column set equal to 'MAIN' next to one of the numbers.  But if there is not multiple numbers then Type can be equal to anything at all.  In T-SQL, how do I pick the number tagged as 'MAIN' in those cases when there is more than one number but simply select the only number available in those cases where there are not multiple numbers.  Thanks!

Using a subquery on a join would be ideal.. but I can't seem to get it.

CustomerTable:
| ID | Name |
| --- | ----- |
| ID  | ACME Inc  |
| 1   | Foo Bar |

PhoneTable:

| CustID | Type | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blah | 12345 |
| 2 | NULL | 33333 |
| 2 | MAIN | 98765 |

Desired Output:

1, 12345
2, 98765

Comment: Please show the relevant (simplified) schema

Comment: That table doesn't look like schema - can we see each db table in its own content table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to the phone table twice - first for the `MAIN` phone, and again for any phone, and use `coalesce()` to get the first (ie non-null) hit:

```
select
  c.id,
  max(coalesce(p.phone, p2.phone)) as phone_number
from customer c
left join phone_table p on p.cust_id = c.id
  and p.type = 'MAIN'
left join phone_table p2 on p2.cust_id = c.id
group by c.id
```

`max()` is used to return one row only in case there are many non-main phone numbers. If you want them all, remove `max` and the `group by`

Note that the condition `p.type = 'MAIN'` *must* be in the join condition (not in the `where` clause) for this to work.

If you put the condition in the `where` clause, it will force the join to `p` to be an *inner* join and customers without a `MAIN` phone will not be returned.